# Google Place API for Parking Spots

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I have just used google place API for finding parking spots nearby location. It works great and I am getting response when I make simple GET Request to Google place API.

Here is the URL for sending Simple Request to get Parking Spots for the near by location

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=LAT,LONG&radius=500&types=parking&sensor=false&key=APIKEY
```

And when I pass lat long for my current city, then I am getting:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.027462,
               "lng" : 72.57919699999999
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "6f7c1e623f7d6a70eb612d6f58373c222b5f1c97",
         "name" : "AMC Pay and Park",
         "reference" : "CoQBcwAAAF7ZnmGltBQ7log8OTHxhjqMNZKq2wQTffbXmTI2u4Lm-QXhAOVTxwK2Lu_SSuZgdQ1uVMLmo9hhJhXHT7Loa4LEzqOePfGwJvZ3pGbEFdg7fEGsqaNdNpVnw0hMUK4qFkBlh5fstFAoanUGJ5LRistdJI7otAwQ-bWQIPXH_DJXEhCTkcSIZq-69YHIURouswj7GhTCyO-tz0DiTdVozVlBBqiC15T4OA",
         "types" : [ "parking", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Khanpur, Amdavad"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 23.026521,
               "lng" : 72.583656
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "37ba75c2dd455b0c63c207f17fdbb27bb11951bb",
         "name" : "AMC Parking",
         "reference" : "CnRuAAAAXfjCgAfzvpuB3Bp_iWgXFnPp3O_I24ozqvfKnzND1jH5pZ5y_skNlCDSyworLODMTjJ7Bx9EabdRsaWuoWGYnb4W5axP9unFvprwftoDfAbWFS0RQREl01mCyeU-jO56izs9Q6KerrPkbZR2M_E9NRIQ5gVcDojpihbQQGDhjHDvAxoUhJTBKuodC-bBz_Ovdq4cbu67eQk",
         "types" : [ "parking", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Relief Rd, Gheekanta, Bhadra, Amdavad"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Okay my query is that, are those data live/real?

As I have seen Card2Go & http://www.parkwhiz.com/developers/ is providing very nice data, it's real and updating very frequently.

The reason why I am not using Car2Go and ParkWhiz is because these services are available for only specific countries. I don't want to make my application for only specific country. So I have decided to use Google Place API for Parking Spots. I think Google Data is not updated as frequently as Car2Go and ParkWhiz API's data is updated. Isn't it?

Is it okay to use Google API for Finding Nearest Parking Spots? Another question, is Google providing Data for Street Parking As well?

If any one have some nice suggestions regarding this, then it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: No, Google API's Data are not real time, While they have a huge database which they update continuously. While Car2Go has it's own database maintained for the updates from it's own app as well as from other means like Google and others. So as soon as any updated information is entered it will pushed to the app accordingly.

Comment: Did you manage to find a free option that supported multiple countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Aamirkan - The best parking API our there is parkme.com. Highest quality of data. Most countries served. Real time. Etc. Did you look at that?

https://www.parkme.com/how-it-works#api

Full disclosure - I work for them :-)

Comment: Hey Keith, I have been trying to contact Parkme for a couple of week several times, but get no response! It would be great to hear back from you

Comment: Could you send me credentials for testing the API?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

or probably you can have a mix approach to use all API's available. If you feel the API from car2go gives better result than google then use car2go api in country wherever its available. For the rest of the places you can rely on google places api.